ld return some error when link some object file with other
I use nasm to compile this assembly code and link it with some other output file 'i686-elf':
global x86_Video_GetVbeInfo
x86_Video_GetVbeInfo:

    ; make new call frame
    push ebp             ; save old call frame
    mov ebp, esp          ; initialize new call frame

    x86_EnterRealMode

    ; save modified regs
    push edi
    push es
    push ebp                ; bochs vbe changes ebp

    ; call interrupt
    mov ax, 0x4f00
    LinearToSegOffset [bp + 8], es, edi, di
    int 10h

    ; check return
    cmp al, 4fh
    jne .error
    
    ; put status in eax
    mov al, ah
    and eax, 0xFF
    jmp .cont

.error:
    mov eax, -1

.cont:
    ; restore regs
    pop ebp                ; bochs vbe changes ebp
    pop es
    pop ebx

    push eax

    x86_EnterProtectedMode

    pop eax

    ; restore old call frame
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

My linking command:
i686-elf-ld -T ../src/linker.ld -o ../binary/isolation/rcmiracle.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib ../binary/compiler_out/x86.o ../binary/compiler_out/boot.o ../binary/compiler_out/kernel.o -lgcc

nasm doesn't return any errors, but ld gives me some abstruse error:
../binary/compiler_out/x86.o: in function `x86_Video_GetVbeInfo':
../src/x86.asm:(.text+0x44): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'
../binary/compiler_out/x86.o: in function `x86_Video_GetVbeInfo.pmode16':
../src/x86.asm:(.text+0x51): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'

I tried to modify my linker script but no result. Any ideas?

This is not a [mcve] as it is missing the definition of  various macros. Anyway, use objdump -dr x86.o to see the relocations so you can spot the R_386_16 and fix them. You likely loaded an address into a 16 bit register.

So this is from nanobytes' excellent OS tutorial. x86_EnterRealMode in that tutorial is in stage2 bootloader and is written with assumption the code is somewhere in first 64Kb of RAM. So, if your x86_EnterRealMode is that x86_EnterRealMode  then it is likely your linker script places your code somewhere higher than 64Kb (which is normal for kernel but incompatible with that PM->RM switch code)

Yes, i checked my linker script and modify some value in it, now it works.
